# ToAsyncEnumerable.ToList() throwing error after migrating the ef core to 3.1.0

Tags: c#

I migrated Ef core from 2.2.6 to 3.1.0 i am getting the error for the below code

```
var listOfRecords = repo.GetOne("Test", 1).ToAsyncEnumerable().ToList();

        Assert.Single(listOfRecords.Result);
```

I understand in 3.1 we cannot use 'ToAsyncEnumerable' but how to fix this issue??

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @the_joric Error CS1061 'Task<ILevelDisplayName>' does not contain a definition for 'ToAsyncEnumerable' and no accessible extension method 'ToAsyncEnumerable' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<ILevelDisplayName>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What does GetOne return?

Comment: @the_joric Task<ILevelDisplayName> returns custom model

Comment: You *can* use `ToAsyncEnumerable()` with EF Core 3.1.` Error CS1061 'Task<ILevelDisplayName>'` means this has nothing to do with EF Core or IAsyncEnumerable - the method returns only one result. There's no point in using `ToAsyncEnumerable().ToList()`, the data is already loaded, it's a single object

Comment: If `GetOne()` returns one item or null, the check should be `Assert.NotNull(record);` or whatever assertion your unit testing library uses

Answer (score 4):

If your function returns a Task of a single object, then couldn't you do:

```
var record = await GetOne("Test", 1);
```

Comment: If i do that then i am getting the error in the next line : Assert.Single(listOfRecords.Result); - cannot convert from model class to system.collections.ienumerable

Comment: @HarshaMullangi it's a *single* object, not an array. There's no point in checking if it has 1 or more items. And using `.Result` is *definitely* not needed

Comment: I have fixed this but with 3.1 migration i am getting error in  entity.HasOne(d => d.ContentControl)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Content)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ContentControlId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Content_ContentControl");

Comment: That's not related to this question. You should make a new question with the error details.